# Passing ARN reference from CloudFormation to Swagger

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cloudformation

We are trying to automate the deployment of AWS lambda and API gateway using Amazon CloudFormation and Swagger. Towards this, we have created a CloudFormation template to create the Lambda and other resources required for APIGateway (including the endpoints). We would like to import the API definitions from an external swagger file so that the same CloudFormation template can be used for multiple lambdas and APIGateways. Is there a way we can refer the ARN of the lambda which has been created by the CloudFormation template in the external swagger file (being referred to in the same CloudFormation template) which holds the API definition?

Swagger content:

```
"x-amazon-apigateway-integration": {
              "uri": "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:function:TestSimpleProxy/invocations",
              "passthroughBehavior": "when_no_match",
              "httpMethod": "POST",
              "type": "aws_proxy"
            }
```

In the above integration method I need to replace the value of the uri dynamically from the cloud formation template.

My cloud formation script is as below:

```
"myApi":{
      "Type" : "AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi",
      "Properties" : {
        "BodyS3Location" : S3Location of the swagger definition file,
        ..,
        ..
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

**New solution:**

It is now possible to use the new [`AWS::Include` Transform](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/create-reusable-transform-function-snippets-and-add-to-your-template-with-aws-include-transform.html) to reference the uploaded template directly from a CloudFormation template:

```
Api:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
  Properties:
    Body:
      Fn::Transform:
        Name: AWS::Include
        Parameters:
          Location: !Sub s3://${ArtifactsBucket}/swagger.yaml
```

where `ArtifactsBucket` refers to the bucket where you upload Swagger spec before you create or update your stack. Then, in the Swagger template itself you can use the intrinsics, e.g.

```
x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
  type: aws_proxy
  httpMethod: POST
  uri:
    Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${LambdaFunction.Arn}/invocations
```

Here I'm using the long `Fn::Sub` notation instead of just `!Sub`, because Swagger doesn't natively support the latter, and also because the docs on `AWS::Include` Transform say that shorthand forms are not supported yet.

You can also use `AWS::Serverless::Api` and `DefinitionBody` if you use [SAM](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model).

**Old workaround:**

Another (somewhat hacky, yet simple) solution is to list the Api as the last resource in the CloudFormation template, and specify an *empty* Body with `: !Sub |-` at the end.

You can then concatenate this template with the actual Swagger file, and reference any parameters using the standard `${}` syntax in that file.

The only minor complication is that you have to properly indent the Swagger file when concatenating it when you're using YAML (this approach won't work for JSON templates though; you'll have to substitute Body with something like `jq` if you use these).

Comment: The official documentation you link to is difficult to understand to say the least. Thanks for the clear example.

Comment: Great answer! 
**1)** What is `LambdaFunction`, is it the name used in `template.yaml` for `AWS::Serverless::Function`?
**2)** Will the same work for `AWS::Serverless::Api`?

Comment: 1) yes, it's just the name of the function; 2) I think it should work in `AWS::Serverless::Api`, but please verify.

Answer (score 2):

There's another, **less complicated** approach.  If you use the `Body` property instead of the `BodyS3Location` of `AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi` you can use the [Cloud Formation Instrinsic Functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference.html) to refer to or dynamically build up the ARN that you want in your swagger template.

... of course the downside is your swagger template is embedded in a CF script rather than in a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

Is that `"x-amazon-apigateway-integration"` part of your CloudFormation template?

If so, then following the example from https://blog.jayway.com/2016/09/18/introduction-swagger-cloudformation-api-gateway/, I think you can use [Ref](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-ref.html) function to pass that information through.

Comment: thanks for the response. The referred example works only if we have hard coded the swagger definition with the cloud formation template itself. If I try to import it from an external file. It is throwing an invalid ARN error.

Comment: Can you share a complete example of a CloudFormation template demonstrating the error?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same obstacle...  This is *NOT* a simple answer but a workaround to automate the resolution of the Lambda ARN that you **want** to use in the swagger template; it's working for me.  Here goes...

1. **Export the Lambda ARN in the CF template** that creates your Lambda and which you want to later use in the swagger template e.g.

   ```
   Outputs:
     MyLambdaARN:
       Value: !Ref "LambdaFuncThatIsDefinedInTheTemplate"
       Export:
         Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-LambdaARN"
   ```
2. **Refer to the Lambda ARN Export within the swagger template** - *In place of the ARN for your lambda*, enter a *replaceable token* that includes the export name from step 1, for example "MyLambdaStack-LambdaARN" if your stack from step 1 was created as "MyLambdaStack".

   - For the token syntax let's use what we **wish** actually worked, the [ImportValue function](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html) so our token becomes `!ImportValue(MyLambdaStack-LambdaARN)`.
   - Within our swagger template, the integration extension uses our token like this:

     ```
     x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
       passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
       uri: "!ImportValue(MyLambdaStack-LambdaARN)"
       httpMethod": "POST"
       type: "AWS-PROXY"
     ```
3. **Replace Token with Actual Lambda ARN** - We'll use the following script to replace the `!ImportValue(MyLambdaStack-LambdaARN)` token with the actual Lambda ARN we need there.

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   SWAGGER_FILE=$1

   REPLACEMENTS=$( \
       aws cloudformation list-exports --query 'Exports[*].[Name,Value]'\
       | awk '{print "s/!ImportValue(" $1 ")/" $2 "/g"}' ORS='; '\
   )

   sed "$REPLACEMENTS" "$SWAGGER_FILE"
   ```

   Here's what this script does

   1. Grabs the list of stack exports using `aws cloudformation list-exports`
   2. Filters to just the export name and value with the `--query 'Exports[*].[Name,Value]'` argument
   3. Formats the exports as a string of sed replacements that will replace a token value with the actual export value with `awk '{print "s/!ImportValue(" $1 ")/" $2 "/g"}' ORS='; '`
   4. Finally, uses `sed` to make the replacements in the swagger file passed in as the first argument to the script.

   For example if you created this script as `resolve-arns.sh` you could then invoke it as follows:

   ```
   ./resolve-arns.sh swagger.yml > resolved-swagger.yml
   ```
4. **Reference the Resolved Swagger definition** - Finally, you'd reference the `resolved-swagger.yml` file in the CF template you're using to create your API e.g. `BodyS3Location: resolved-swagger.yml`

**CAVEATS:**

1. Of course the `aws` command line tools need to be available and configured
2. This implementation isn't sophisticated enough to handle an AWS region argument... but it could be modified for that
3. This is a bash script... if you're on a different OS like windows the same approach should work but the implementation would be different (I'd start with powershell probably...)