# Swagger file with AWS Extensions stored in S3 Bucket for API Creation with Cloudformation

Tags: swagger, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create an API Gateway using a Cloudformation template like  this:

```
Resources:
 InvoiceApi:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
  Properties:
    Description: an Api for our Invoicegen App
    Name: !Ref ApiName
    ApiKeySourceType: !Ref ApiKeySourceType
    BinaryMediaTypes:
    - !Ref binaryMediaType1
    - !Ref binaryMediaType2
    BodyS3Location:
     Bucket:
       Fn::ImportValue: !Sub ${EnvironmentName}-SwaggerApiBucket-Name
     Key: swaggertest.yaml
     ETag: !Ref ETag
     EndpointConfiguration:
     Types:
      - REGIONAL
     FailOnWarnings: true
     MinimumCompressionSize: !Ref minimumCompressionSize
```

the Swagger-yaml file on the S3 Bucket looks like this:

```
  swagger: '2.0'
  info:
    version: '2016-08-17T18:08:34Z'
    title: InvoicegenAPI
  basePath: "/LATEST"
  schemes:
   - https
  paths:
    /greeting:
       get:
         summary: Get Greeting
         parameters:
          - name: name
            in: query
            required: false
            type: string
        produces:
          - application/json
        responses:
          '200':
            description: 200 response
        x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
          requestTemplates:
            application/json: '{"name": "$input.params(''name'')"}'
          uri:
            Fn::Join:
             - ''
             - - 'arn:aws:apigateway:'
               - Ref: AWS::Region
               - ":lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/"
               - Fn::GetAtt:
                 - InvoiceLambda
                 - Arn
               - "/invocations"
         responses:
           default:
             statusCode: '200'
         httpMethod: POST
         type: aws
```

unfortunately it throws an error like this:

```
Unable to parse API definition because of a malformed integration at path /greeting. (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: 2cf08a97-e66f-11e8-afee-fb6b03568b64)
```

I double checked the Swagger file, all the indents seem fine. What am I missing?

There is a thread dealing with this issue already but has not yielded any solution yet.

[Passing ARN reference from CloudFormation to Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41266488/passing-arn-reference-from-cloudformation-to-swagger)

merci in advance

A

Comment: The indents for `summary`, `parameters`, `Fn::Join` and `type: aws` are off. Paste your YAML into http://editor.swagger.io to see the errors.

Comment: No, that was not the issue, it has something to do with the AWS integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you problem is on using the `BodyS3Location` property for the referenced S3 file, which is probably not parsing the YAML file, therefore not resolving your instricic functions.

My suggestion is that you change to Body + [AWS::Include](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/create-reusable-transform-function-snippets-and-add-to-your-template-with-aws-include-transform.html) Transform, similar to what was suggested on [Passing ARN reference from CloudFormation to Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41266488/passing-arn-reference-from-cloudformation-to-swagger#42779465). Try this as your Resource:

```yaml
Resources:
 InvoiceApi:
  Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
  Properties:
    Description: an Api for our Invoicegen App
    Name: !Ref ApiName
    ApiKeySourceType: !Ref ApiKeySourceType
    BinaryMediaTypes:
    - !Ref binaryMediaType1
    - !Ref binaryMediaType2
    Body:
      Fn::Transform:
        Name: AWS::Include
        Parameters:
          Location: !Sub 's3://${EnvironmentName}-SwaggerApiBucket-Name/swaggertest.yaml'
    EndpointConfiguration:
    Types:
    - REGIONAL
    FailOnWarnings: true
    MinimumCompressionSize: !Ref minimumCompressionSize
```