# Permission issue on resource arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:aws:transform

Tags: amazon-web-services, swagger, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, openapi

I am trying to integrate swagger with api gateway and lambda using swagger extensions. Swagger file is uploaded in a S3 bucket, I am using Body with transform and include as below

Using BodyS3Location in AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi properties returns error Unable to parse API definition because of a malformed integration for the same integration mentioned above I referred [Swagger file with AWS Extensions stored in S3 Bucket for API Creation with Cloudformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53261354/swagger-file-with-aws-extensions-stored-in-s3-bucket-for-api-creation-with-cloud).

and modified the template as below for AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi properties

`Body:
  Fn::Transform:
    Name: AWS::Include
      Parameters:
        Location:
          Fn::Sub: "s3://${BucketName}/apiSwaggerSpec.yaml"`

For the stack above I have all the permission on cloudformation actions

Below code I have added as swagger extension.

`x-amazon-apigateway-auth:
  type: "aws_iam"
x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
  type: "aws_proxy"
  httpMethod: "POST"
  passthroughBehavior: "when_no_match"
  uri:
    Fn::Sub: "arn:aws:apigateway:us-east-1:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:${accountId}:function:testLambdaFunction/invocations"
  credentials:
    Fn::Sub: "arn:aws:iam::${accountId}:role/${myRole}"
  responses:
    default:
      statusCode: 200`

I am getting permission denied error with message as 
myrole is not authorized to perform cloudformation:CreateChangeSet on resource: arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:aws:transform/include

Do I need to add special permissions for transform/include. aws documentation says it doesn't need special permissions?

Comment: Is your CloudFormation Role able to access the Swagger-File in the Bucket, i.e. does it have the permissions to do so?

Comment: yes, bucket is public and for "myRole" I have "cloudformation:*" actions allowed for the stacks with prefix "apiGlobal", Here my stack name is apiGlobal

Comment: @Steve did you manage to solve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

I hit this same problem, and this question was the only meaningful result I could find when searching. Despite AWS's claims to the contrary, there does appear to be a required permission, but the one that the error message complains about seems to be the only one; after that, the Include transform appears to work. This is the entire policy I added:

```
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          - # The AWS::Include transform requires this weird permission.
            Sid: UseInclude
            Effect: "Allow"
            Action: "cloudformation:CreateChangeSet"
            Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:cloudformation:${AWS::Region}:aws:transform/Include"
```