# Serverless Deployment API Gateway with Lambda Integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, swagger, serverless, openapi

I'm attempting to deploy a lambda function with API gateway lambda integration. My api specification is written in openAPI 3 in an external yml file.

I would like to pass the name of the arn of the lambda into the api specification.

My serverless.yml:

```
service: my-test-service
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: java8

functions:
  mylambda-test:
    handler: com.sample.MyHandler
    name: mylambda-test
    description: test lambda with api gateway
    package:
      artifact: myexample-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
          individually: true
resources:
  Resources:
    ApiGatewayRestApi:
      Type: AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi
      Properties:
        Name: test-api
        Body:
          ${file(api.yml)}
```

in the api.yml:

```
openapi: "3.0.1"
info:
  title: "test-api"
  version: "0.0.1-oas3"

paths:
  /test:
     get:
       *
       *
       *
        x-amazon-apigateway-integration: 
          uri: {arn of mylambda-test}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing ARN reference from CloudFormation to Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41266488/passing-arn-reference-from-cloudformation-to-swagger)

Answer (score -1):

How about using [endly e2e](http://github.com/viant/endly/) runner to deploy and setup your API gatweay

the deployment workflow may looks like the following

```
pipeline:
  setupFunction1:
    action: aws/lambda:deploy
    credentials: $awsCredentials
    functionname: $functionName1
    runtime:  go1.x
    handler: loginfo
    code:
      zipfile: $LoadBinary(${codeZip})
    rolename: lambda-loginfo-executor
    define:
      - policyname: s3-${functionName}-role
        policydocument: $Cat('${privilegePolicy}')
    attach:
      - policyarn: arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole

  setupFunction2:
    action: aws/lambda:deploy
    credentials: $awsCredentials
    functionname: $functionName2
    runtime:  go1.x
    handler: loginfo
    code:
      zipfile: $LoadBinary(${codeZip})
    rolename: lambda-loginfo-executor
    define:
      - policyname: s3-${functionName}-role
        policydocument: $Cat('${privilegePolicy}')
    attach:
      - policyarn: arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole

  setupAPI:
    action: aws/apigateway:setupRestAPI
    credentials: aws
    '@name': loginfoAPI
    resources:
      - path: /path1
        methods:
          - httpMethod: ANY
            functionname: $functionName1
      - path: /path2
          methods:
              - httpMethod: ANY
                functionname: $functionName2    
  sleepTimeMs: 15000
  post:
  endpointURL: ${setupAPI.EndpointURL}
```

Here is example of deployment  [workflow](https://github.com/adrianwit/serverless_e2e/blob/master/lambda/e2e/regression/cases/002_logs_count/deploy.yaml)

You can also check out actual examples implmeneting e2e testing with lambda including [API Gateway](https://github.com/adrianwit/serverless_e2e/tree/master/lambda#http-apigateway)